# Group report together, possibly with SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called Register which contains the following fields:

> Date, AMPM, Mark.

A day can have two records for a day. Its fairly easy to select and display all the records in a list ordered by date ascending.

What I would like to do is display the data as a grid. Something along the lines of.

```
         | Mon | Tues| Wed| Thurs| Fri | Sat
9/8/2014 | /\  | /P  | /\ |   L  | /\  | /
```

Have a week beginning and then group the 5 together. I'm not even sure sql is the best option for this, but the groupby commands seem to suggest it may be able to do this.

The Data structure is as follows.

```
Date, AMPM, Mark
9/8/2014, AM, /
9/8/2014, PM, \
9/9/2014, AM, /
9/9/2014, PM, P
9,10,2014, AM, /
9,10,2014, PM, \
9,11,2014, PM, L
```

....

The mark field can contain a number of letters. P for instance means they are participating in a sporting activity. L means they were late.

Does anyone have any resources they can point me towards the right direction that would be helpful. I'm not even sure what this type of report is called and whether I should be using SQL or javascript to group this data in a presentable format. The / \ represents AM and the a PM.

Comment: Rather than asking for a library, which is offtopic for SO, perhaps you could describe your input and output better and we could help you create a custom solution.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What does the `P` and `L` mean?

Comment: I'm using sqllite, analysing this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query would get you the desired result. If you need Sunday also, you'll have to add a small condition to test for `when days_after_last_Monday = 6` in the `CASE` statement.

```
select
  last_Monday Week_Starting,
  max(
    case
      when days_after_last_Monday = 0 then mark
      else null
    end) Mon,   --if the # of days between previous Monday and reg_date is zero, then get the according mark
   max(
     case
      when days_after_last_Monday = 1 then mark
      else null
     end) Tues,
   max(
     case
      when days_after_last_Monday = 2 then mark
      else null
     end) Wed,
   max(
     case
      when days_after_last_Monday = 3 then mark
      else null
     end) Thurs,
   max(
     case
      when days_after_last_Monday = 4 then mark
      else null
     end) Fri,
   max(
     case
      when days_after_last_Monday = 5 then mark
      else null
     end) Sat
from
(
  select 
    reg_date,
    last_Monday,
    julianday(reg_date) - julianday(last_Monday) as days_after_last_monday,   --determine the number of days between previous Monday and reg_date
    mark
  from
  (
    select
      reg_date,
      case 
        when cast (strftime('%w', reg_date) as integer) = 1 then date(reg_date, 'weekday 1')
        else date(reg_date, 'weekday 1', '-7 days') 
      end last_monday,    --determine the date of previous Monday
      mark
    from
    (
      select 
        reg_date,
        group_concat(mark, '') mark  --concatenate am and pm marks for each reg_date
      from
      (
        SELECT
          reg_date,
          ampm,
          mark
        FROM register
        order by reg_date, ampm  --order by ampm so that am rows are selected before pm
      )
      group by reg_date
    )
  )
)
group by last_Monday
order by last_Monday;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4b7a7/2)</kbd>